# How to convert a protobuf message into a series of bytes?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am using C++ generated protobuf code, and I have a message type defined like this in my .proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    int32 num = 1;
    string fooString = 2;
}
```

In my C++ code, I am using it like:

```
Foo foo;
foo.set_num(1);
food.set_fooString("foo_as_string");
std::string fooAsString;
foo.SerializeToString(&fooAsString);
```

I then try to send this over http.  My expectation is that SerializeToString converts the message to bytes that are then stored in the std::string fooAsString.  Is that how this works?  When I get my http response, it just includes the direct field values:

```
foo_as_string 1
```

How can I encode my protobuf message into bytes to send over the wire?

Comment: I'm unfamililar with the CPP implementation of Protobuf but, similar to other implementations, yes, `SerializeToString` generates the on-the-wire (marshaled) message. You can confirm this by capturing the file of `fooAsString` in a file (e.g. `foo.bin`) and piping it into protoc to decode the message: `protoc --proto_path=${PWD} --decode=Foo ${PWD}/foo.proto < foo.bin`

Comment: You write that "When I get my http response" but you don't include the server implementation and so we've no information by which we can help explain what it returns.

Comment: I've been calling my server using curl like this:
         curl -X GET -k --header "Accept: application/octet-stream; Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -"http://localhost:3000/getfoo"